# observables dependent on one another for their own values - circular references

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Probably a knockout newbie question.  I just started learning knockout this week.

I have two observables - width and height. These values are initially set by grabbing the width and height of a clicked element, so no calculation is needed for this part.  The issue is that, once the initial values are captured, I want to maintain the aspect ratio for all future changes.  So if the user updates the width, I want the height to update in accordance with the aspect ratio (original width / original height).  So when a user changes the width, the height must change, and vice versa.

I have tried this using subscribers, but this causes an infinite loop as you might expect, as any change to the width requires a change in height and vice versa.  I have looked into computed observables and extenders, but I am not sure either one is the right answer, though this may be due to my limited experience with knockout.

If necessary, I can provide some code, but thought I'd try to keep this conceptual if possible.  Just something to point me down the right path.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with any circular dependency, you have to break the cycle.  Rather than having two mutually dependent observables, make them dependent on one or more common observables.  Observables that can maintain that ratio.

e.g.,

```
function Proportional (width, height) {
    var _ratio = width / height,
        _width = ko.observable(width),
        _height = ko.observable(height);

    this.width = ko.dependentObservable({ read: _width, write: setWidth });
    this.height = ko.dependentObservable({ read: _height, write: setHeight });

    function setWidth(width) {
        _width(width);
        _height(width / _ratio);
    }
    function setHeight(height) {
        _height(height);
        _width(height * _ratio);
    }
}

function ViewModel(data) {
    var p = new Proportional(data.width, data.height);
    this.width = p.width;
    this.height = p.height;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/nc8mmg73/)

Comment: Thank you very much.  This looks like a great way to solve the issue.